# Blackberry 10 - Assets Warning

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, qnx

Recently started learning and developing(QML with momentics ide) for BB10 and the applications seem to work. However while building I've been getting warning ".Assets need to be packaged only once".
All the icons and images have been placed in the assets folder.
I've noticed after building that within the .bar file duplicate copies of the icons and images outside the asset folder are created automatically and the file size just bloats up.
Any help on these.

Am I placing the images in the wrong location?

All the icons and splash screen images were set/edited using bar-descriptor file in the ide.

Would appreciate help or suggestions on this

Comment: Read in the manifest in XML mode view, and check if there is only one splashscreen/icon defined for each size

Comment: Is every image duplicated, or only icons/splashscreens?